# How can I keep relative path when open project from template

Tags: visual-studio

This is a snippet of my csproj file:

```
 <Compile Include="$(SolutionDir)\..\xxx\Toolbox\Toolbox.cs">
          <Link>xxx\Toolbox.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
```

I made an template export of this project but when I create a new one based on the template the file Toolbox.cs will not reference one level above SolutionDir\xxx\Toolbox.cs.
Instead VS replace the file location with the path where the template is located.
How can I tell VS to keep the path as it is with no replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Edit MyTemplate.vstemplate inside the exported template zip file and add
true in the TemplateData section.

Now it works.